# Floating input field (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have AJAX call that generate html

Here is this html code on ajax request

```
 var videoHTML = '<div style="width:100%;overflow-y: hidden;background:white;height:60%;border-bottom:solid;border-color: #A9A9A9;">' 
                 + '<div style="float:left; width:50%;height:288px;border-right:solid;border-color: #A9A9A9;margin-bottom:10px;">' 
                 + '<video  style="width:100%;height:290px; object-fit: contain;padding-right: 15px;padding-left:15px;" controls>';
  videoHTML += '<source src="' + document.location.origin + "/uploads/" 
               + question2[i].Linkes + ".webm" + '" type="video/webm">';
  videoHTML += '</video>' 
               + '</div>' 
               + '<div style="float:right;width:48%;text-align:center;height:296px;padding-top:5px;">' 
               + '<div class="qustion-div-two" style="height:80%;margin-top:20px; background:white;" >' 
               + '<div id="comments" style="width: 100%; height: 70%;">' + '</div>' 
               + '<div id="write_field" style="width:100%;height:30%;font-size:15px;">' 
               +'<input type="text" required>' 
               + ' <span class="highlight">' 
               + '</span>' 
               + '<span class="bar">' 
               + '</span>'
               +  '</div>' 
               + '</div>' 
               +  '</div>';
```

My problem in this `<input type="text" required>`, sometimes this field on bottom, sometimes on top after refreshing page.

Where is problem may be?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution

I need to write this `position: relative;` in div that contains in parent div.

So my code now is

`+ '<div id="write_field" style="width:100%;height:30%;font-size:15px;position: relative;">'`